# How to add target=_blank to all PDF links inside div using jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, xhtml

**For example:**

I want to add `target=_blank` in any PDF link comes inside this css class `"class="newWindow"`

Before adding script

```
<div class="newWindow" >

<a href="pdf1.pdf">link text</a>
<a href="pdf2.pdf">link text</a>

</div>
```

After adding script

```
<div class="newWindow" >

<a href="Pdf1.pdf" target="_blank">link text</a>
<a href="Pdf2.pdf" target="_blank">link text</a>

</div>
```

**Please provide jquery code with no conflict.**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### Code

```
$(".newWindow a[href$='pdf']").attr('target','_blank');
```

:]

#### Preview:

http://jsbin.com/ojapo

#### View code

http://jsbin.com/ojapo/edit

#### Note:

in jsbin example, I also add class `.bl`, so you can easily see result :]

#### No Conflict mode:

```
jQuery.noConflict();
jQuery(".newWindow a[href$='pdf']").attr('target','_blank');
```

or

```
 jQuery.noConflict();
 
 jQuery(document).ready(function($){
   $(".newWindow a[href$='pdf']").attr('target','_blank');
 });
```

or another way, take a look here: http://docs.jquery.com/Using_jQuery_with_Other_Libraries

Comment: @alexn: and I has previewzzz ! :D

Comment: how to make this in noconflict mode

Comment: @jitendra: see no conflict version :]

Comment: This is fastest answer including example for me on SO yet

Comment: copy/past version for every .pdf link on page: `$("a[href$='.pdf']").attr('target','_blank');`

Answer (score 0):

This should work

```
$(".newWindow a[href$='.pdf']").attr("target", "_blank");
```